# How do you make a picture look like it's coming out of a circle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

How do you make a picture look like it's coming out of a circle?
Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Tons of different ways to achieve this.  Given the nature of the question, I will share a simple approach.

**Photography:**
The picture will require the graphic artist to cut the subject out. (in this case a cat/dog)

**How To:**

1. Using the "Polygonal Lasso Tool", cut the cat/dog out of the
   picture.
2. With the subject cutout, on a new layer, create a circle using the Ellipse tool.  This tool will allow you to add color, borders,
   shadows to both the inside and stoke of the shape. You will want to
   make the circle smaller than the subject cutout so it gives the
   illusion of coming out of the circle.
3. With the shape created on one layer and the subject cut out, make sure the subject layer is above the circle layer and drag it on
   top of the circle you created.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I would try:

1. Select the cat/dog.
2. Create a mask to isolate the cat/dog.
3. Make a copy of the masked cat/dog and hide it. Make sure the new copied layer is on top of the original layer.
4. Create a circle and keep its layer below both of the cat/dog layers.
5. Right click on the name of the cat/dog layer that is directly above the circle layer and select "create clipping mask". The cat/dog should now be cropped along the boundaries of the circle.
6. Unhide the top cat/dog layer and select its mask in the layer panel.
7. Use the brush tool to remove any part of the animal that you do not want to have coming out of circle and leave the rest (make sure the brush's foreground color is black and opacity is 100%).